# how to overrule all color statements in latex to get all text in 1 color

Tags: latex, textcolor

I have a latex file with quite some text highlighted in another color using the \textcolor{}{} statement. But regularly I need to output the full document with only black text (I keep updating the document with colored text).

I am therefore looking for a way to set all text color in the entire document in such a way that it overrules the individual \textcolor statements. Is that possible? If not, what would be the most efficient way to do this? I don't want to manually remove all those \textcolor statements every time..

I have really tried to search before asking but I couldn't find it, so I think/hope it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147117/178369

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `monochrome` option of xcolor:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
monochrome
]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{test}
\textcolor{cyan}{test}
\textcolor{violet}{test}
\textcolor{orange}{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awsome, thanks a lot!! It did not fully work in my case but when I put 'monochrome' in the document class it works.